# Cloning or duplicating feature within feature class using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, copy, paste

Is there a way to copy selected features, then paste them into the same feature class (and then edit some attributes)?

e.g. If I have a land parcel that has more than one owner, how can I create multiple instances of that feature without having to import or load it for each owner?  I just want to copy and paste it then edit the 'Owner' field.

Comment: I have 15 of these stations to draw. I want to draw one with all the valves ect and then copy it 15 times what is the best way to do this? I am using Arcmap 10.8.2
[![pump stations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Fww.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5Fww.png)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.  Within an active editing session you can simply use the Copy and Paste tools on the main tool bar.  I dialogue window will pop-up asking you which layer you want to paste it into.  A second option is to use the Copy Features Tool that is part of the Advanced Editing Toolbar.  This tool will also pop-up a window asking you which layer you would like to save the feature to (assuming you may have multiple layers loaded in ArcMap).

Comment: Thanks - I had been trying to achive this by copying features selected in the attributes table, not the feature itself.  It seems so obvious now.

Comment: Glad its working.

Comment: A frustration saving note to this: if you use the buttons you must clear your selection after hitting copy.  If you don't and hit paste it does nothing and doesn't bring up the paste to layer dialog window.

Answer (score 4):

Surely it would be better to create an "Owner Table" and relate the feature class to the owner table. Good GIS practice !

OR a less pretty way would be to have multiple fields in the feature class e.g. Owner1, Owner2 etc.